# cola de prioridad java

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos, diseño-de-clases, queue

Tengo un problema, estoy haciendo un proyecto, consiste en ingresas datos de una persona (nombre, edad y lugar(distancia)) a la hora dar los datos por ejemplo:

Persona 1: fulano, 32 años, 34 kilómetros

Persona 2: jorge, 54 años, 44 kilómetros

Persona 3: esteban, 98 años, 14 kilómetros

Persona 4: baldo, 28 años, 98 kilómetro

Persona 5: Lolo, 67 años, 70 kilómetros

estas personas me las va guardando en una cola....y a la hora de (atender) imprimir me los manda en orden de la edad de mayor a menor; me da como resultado asi:

(con sus datos cada uno)

Persona 3

Persona 5

Persona 2

Persona 1

Persona 4

lo quiero hacer imprimir con la condición de que si la persona es mayor de 65 se imprima (atienda) como valla llegando, pero si es menor de 65 ,se atenderá (imprimir) primero la persona que tenga mas kilómetros...así:

(con sus datos cada uno)

Persona 3  (es mayor de 65 sale primero) 98 años

Persona 5 (es mayor de 65 sale después del primero) 67 años

Persona 4 (es menor de 65 pero tiene mas kilómetros) 98 km

Persona 2 (es menor de 65 pero tiene menos km que persona 4) 44 km

Persona 1 (es menor de 65 pero tiene menos km que persona 2) 34 km

espero que me entiendan:   Aquí la condición con lo que hago eso,,,,

clase persona

public class Persona implements Comparable {

```
private String nombre;//nombre
private int tipo; //edad
private int com;//kilometros

public int getCom() {
    return com;
}

public void setCom(int com) {
    this.com = com;
}

public Persona(String nombre, int tipo,int com) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.tipo = tipo;
    this.com=com;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public int getTipo() {
    return tipo;
}

public void setTipo(int tipo) {
    this.tipo = tipo;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Persona o) {
    if (tipo < o.getTipo()) {
        return 1;
    } else if (tipo > o.getTipo()) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

}

clase main

import colaesperaconurgencia.Persona;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Queue;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Queue<Persona> cola = new PriorityQueue<Persona>();
    //int de=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("edad"));
    int de=1;
    while (de>0){
    String fde=(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("nombre"));
    de=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("edad"));
    int d=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("distancia"));


       //fde= Nombre
       //de=edad
       //d=kilometros
    cola.add(new Persona(fde, de,d));


    }

    while (!cola.isEmpty()) {
        Persona a = cola.remove();
        System.out.println(a.getNombre()+ a.getEdad()+a.getKilometros());
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que el problema que tenés es que implementas de manera incorrecta el compareTo. En el compareTo realizado solamente existe la condición que hace que se ordene de mayor a menor dependiendo la edad. Pero la condición indicada por kilometraje no está incluida en ningún lado.

**Mi solución:**

```
public class Persona implements Comparable<Persona> {

private String nombre;// nombre
private int tipo; // edad
private int com;// kilometros

public Persona(String nombre, int tipo, int com) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.tipo = tipo;
    this.com = com;
}

public int getCom() {
    return com;
}

public void setCom(int com) {
    this.com = com;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public int getTipo() {
    return tipo;
}

public void setTipo(int tipo) {
    this.tipo = tipo;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Persona o) {
    Integer miTipo = Integer.valueOf(this.tipo);
    Integer otroTipo = Integer.valueOf(o.getTipo());

    return miTipo < 65 && otroTipo < 65 ? Integer.valueOf(o.getCom()).compareTo(this.com) : otroTipo.compareTo(mTipo);

}
```

}

Aquí he implementado la condición de que, si las dos personas son menores de 65 años, la comparación se realice por kilometraje. En otro caso, se compara por edad.

**Main de prueba:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Persona p1 = new Persona("p1", 32, 34);
    Persona p2 = new Persona("p2", 54, 44);
    Persona p3 = new Persona("p3", 98, 14);
    Persona p4 = new Persona("p4", 28, 98);
    Persona p5 = new Persona("p5", 67, 70);

    List<Persona> lista = new ArrayList<Persona>();

    lista.add(p1);
    lista.add(p2);
    lista.add(p3);
    lista.add(p4);
    lista.add(p5);

    Collections.sort(lista);

    for (Persona persona : lista) {
        System.out.println("La persona tomada es: " + persona.getNombre());
    }

    System.exit(0);
}

}
```

**Mis resultados:** 
La persona tomada es: p3 
La persona tomada es: p5 
La persona tomada es: p4 
La persona tomada es: p2 
La persona tomada es: p1

*Aclaración:* Mi prueba se basó en comprobar que el comparador funcione de manera correcta. Utilicé otro main debido a que me pareció más sencilla la prueba al no realizar optionpane ni nada por el estilo.

Comment: ok, muchas gracias me ha sido de gran ayuda eso.

Comment: buenisimo. si te sirvio ponele +1 asi puedo + puedo desbloqeuar opciones para que se me facilite ayudar a los demas.